# ActionLink MVC4 Razor with icon class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this code HTML:

```
<a class="tooltip-tip2 ajax-load" href="...."><i class="entypo-menu"></i><span>Page Example</span></a>
```

And I would use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Crea mensilizzazione " + s.nome, "CheckCredentials", "giornaliero", new { @class= "tooltip-tip2 ajax-load" , id=s.id, isScuole = false},null)
```

How can add the `<i class="entypo-menu"></i>` in this @HTML.ActionLink???

Comment: You can't set inner html content using the standard helpers.

Comment: And so...How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `ActionLink` helper can accomplish this.  but you can use [`@Url.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) in custom markup to accomplish the same thing:

```
<a class="tooltip-tip2 ajax-load" href="@Url.Action("CheckCredentials", "giornaliero")"><i class="entypo-menu"></i><span>Page Example</span></a>
```

`Url.Action` basically just creates the URL for the link, not any of the markup related to building the link itself.  So it can be used in all sorts of custom client-side code.  (For example, another common use is to embed it in some JavaScript code to define an AJAX service URL.)

**Edit:**  You can add route values exactly the same way as you do with `@Html.ActionLink`:

```
@Url.Action("CheckCredentials", "giornaliero", new { id = s.id, isScuole = false })
```

Comment: with your solution how can add the  {id=s.id, isScuole = false} for the controller?

Comment: @AlessioDeCastro: Are you sure those are route values for the controller?  In your example they're in the same collection as HTML attributes for the markup.  (I don't remember which collection is which in the `Html.ActionLink` method, but they're definitely different collections.)  If you need to add route values, you can do so exactly the same way as you do with `Html.ActionLink`.  Check the available method overloads in the link.

Comment: Yes I am sure! This is the controller code:[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CheckCredentials(int id, bool isScuole, string IsType)
        {
            var model = new CredenzialiViewModel() { Sede_id = id, IsScuole = isScuole, IsType = IsType };
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: @AlessioDeCastro: In that case your original example was already broken.  It's ok though, you can still specify route values in `Url.Action`.  I've included this in the answer as an example.